# How to import dictionary from CSV with empty line correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have this code and it creates the dictionary perfectly fine it just keeps creating an extra dictionary entry of '':1 at the very end of the dictionary which I don't need and I don't know how to stop it doing this can someone please help?

```
with open('coors.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    mydict = {columns[0]: 1 for columns in reader}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a blank line at the end of your CSV file, which is treated by `csv.reader` as a row with one column of an empty value.

You can simply filter out the empty column with an `if` clause in your dict comprehension:

```
mydict = {column: 1 for column, *_ in reader if column}
```